# Turpentine + Varnish, extremely slow (30s+) when using SSL

Tags: ssl, https, varnish, turpentine

I'm new to Turpentine and Varnish, here are my settings:

## nginx -> varnish -> nginx -> php5-fpm

Varnish works fine when I set nginx to listen to port 80 then forward to varnish without using ssl (not directly running varnish on 80), it works fine, cached page is fast, the first hit is slightly slower (first hit about 200ms, cached page hit about 7-20 ms).

Then I try to wrap varnish with https, firstly I tested it with self-signed certificate, the first hit became slow as hell (**30s+**, yes, seconds, not ms), cached hit is still fast, 7-20ms.Then I get a certificate from letsencrypt.org, but it did not fix the issue.

I don't quite understand what is going on here and have no clue on how to find out what's causing it to be so slow.

edit: There is no significant RAM or CPU usage increase during the 30s wait.

## nginx config for varnish

```
upstream varnish{
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    server_name                 store1.mydomain.com store2.mydomain.com store3.mydomain.com; # I actually have 3 store front
    listen                      80;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy{
        proxy_pass          http://varnish;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    Ssl-Offloaded "1";
    }
}

server {
    server_name                 store1.mydomain.com store2.mydomain.com store3.mydomain.com; # I actually have 3 store front
    listen                      443;
    ssl                         on;
    ssl_certificate             /path/to/my/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         /path/to/my/key.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout         10m;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                 ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy{
        proxy_pass          http://varnish;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    Ssl-Offloaded "1";
    }
}
```

## nginx config for php5-fpm

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server_name store1.mydomain.com store2.mydomain.com store3.mydomain.com;
    root /path/to/magento;

    if ($host = 'store1.mydomain.com'){
        set $runcode store1;
    }
    if ($host = 'store2.mydomain.com'){
        set $runcode store2;
    }
    if ($host = 'store3.mydomain.com'){
        set $runcode store3;
    }

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS on; # this is set to on when I'm testing on https, and commented out when I'm using http
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $runcode; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

## varnish configuration file default.vcl generated by turpentine

```
vcl 4.0;
C{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
long a = lrand48();
long b = lrand48();
long c = lrand48();
long d = lrand48();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx",
a,
b & 0xffff,
(b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
(c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
(c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
d
);
return;
}
}C
import std;
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8000";
.first_byte_timeout = 300s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}
backend admin {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8000";
.first_byte_timeout = 21600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 21600s;
}
acl crawler_acl {
"127.0.0.1";
}
acl debug_acl {
}
/* -- REMOVED
sub generate_session {
if (req.url ~ ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session = regsub(
req.url, ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*", "frontend=\1");
} else {
C{
char uuid_buf [50];
generate_uuid(uuid_buf);
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_REQ_VARNISH_FAKED_SESSION =
{ HDR_REQ, "\030X-Varnish-Faked-Session:"};
VRT_SetHdr(ctx,
&VGC_HDR_REQ_VARNISH_FAKED_SESSION,
uuid_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
if (req.http.Cookie) {
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; " + req.http.Cookie;
} else {
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
}
}
sub generate_session_expires {
C{
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm now_tm = *gmtime(&now);
now_tm.tm_sec += 3600;
mktime(&now_tm);
char date_buf [50];
strftime(date_buf, sizeof(date_buf)-1, "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &now_tm);
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_RESP_COOKIE_EXPIRES =
{ HDR_RESP, "\031X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires:"};
VRT_SetHdr(ctx,
&VGC_HDR_RESP_COOKIE_EXPIRES,
date_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
-- */
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts == 0) {
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
}
if (!true || req.http.Authorization ||
req.method !~ "^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS)$" ||
req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") {
return (pipe);
}
if(false) {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url = req.url;
}
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(.*)//+(.*)", "\1/\2");
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
} else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1";
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
set req.backend_hint = admin;
return (pipe);
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/get(?:Block|FormKey)/") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub(
req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub(
req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 &&
!(true || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) {
return (synth(403, "External ESI requests are not allowed"));
}
}
if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=" && !req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl ||
req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session";
} else {
return (pipe);
}
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
unset req.http.Cookie;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
set req.http.X-Varnish-Static = 1;
return (hash);
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|cron\.php)" ||
req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
return (pipe);
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") {
return (pass);
}
if (req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
if (true && req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
if(false) {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url = req.url;
set req.url = req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Origin-Url;
}
return (hash);
}
}
sub vcl_pipe {
unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake;
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}
sub vcl_hash {
if (true && req.http.X-Varnish-Static) {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
return (lookup);
}
if(false && req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Varnish-Cache-Url);
} else {
hash_data(req.url);
}
if (req.http.Host) {
hash_data(req.http.Host);
} else {
hash_data(server.ip);
}
hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded);
if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
}
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) {
hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
return (lookup);
}
sub vcl_hit {
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
set beresp.grace = 15s;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Host = bereq.http.host;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-URL = bereq.url;
if (bereq.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
unset beresp.http.Vary;
set beresp.do_gzip = true;
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
return (deliver);
} else {
if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
unset beresp.http.Expires;
unset beresp.http.Pragma;
unset beresp.http.Cache;
unset beresp.http.Age;
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") {
set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
return (deliver);
} else {
if (true &&
bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
set beresp.ttl = 28800s;
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=28800";
} elseif (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
bereq.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(bereq.http.Cookie,
"^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1");
}
if (bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" &&
bereq.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") {
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub(
bereq.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1");
}
set beresp.ttl = std.duration(
regsub(
bereq.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"),
300s);
if (beresp.ttl == 0s) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
set beresp.uncacheable = true;
return (deliver);
}
} else {
set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
}
}
}
return (deliver);
}
}
sub vcl_deliver {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/";
if (req.http.Host) {
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
} else {
if(req.http.Host ~ "") {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=";
} else {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
}
}
}
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly";
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires;
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private") {
set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache";
}
if (true || client.ip ~ debug_acl) {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store;
} else {
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Host;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-URL;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried using pound to wrap varnish, same issue. nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) varnishd (varnish-4.0.3 revision b8c4a34).

Comment: nginx 1.4.6 ???  also there is something wrong with your magento, have you tried to call https directly to nginx?

Comment: @MagenX I took off varnish, Nginx directly serves php5-fpm with SSL on, it has no issue. About 200ms per page load.

Comment: Could be related to how you're offloading SSL - can you run the same thing without offloading SSL?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a varnish issue now, I set the varnish time out to 3 seconds, now it says timeout. Therefore it is timeout from magento.

Comment: I cleared this field `Crawler IP Addresses` in Turpentine settings in magento backend , and it works now, but I don't quite understand why. Can anyone explain??

Comment: this is strange, because we have few the same setups, i just checked , crawler ip was 127.0.0.1, everything was working... ok then will check this

Comment: @MagenX are u guys running on multi-website, single backend settings as well?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the cause is [SSL Termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy) or [TLS Termination Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy).

I see your setting the SSL in Nginx itself, consider using Pound or if you are using a Load Balancer to terminate the SSL there instead of Nginx.

If you are getting an exact 30 seconds delay then you are hitting a timeout most likely:

- https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/master/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/etc/system.xml#L320

After you disabled the site crawler IP addresses the local loop back for the SSL cookies could be set properly and not attempt to hit the frontend.

More details on setting up SSL for Magento + Turpentine:

- https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/596
- https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/SSL_Support
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

your configuration better be another way,
Varnish in front on port 80, then nginx on port 443 and 8000:

```
        varnish:80 -> nignx:8000 -> php-fpm:9000 
user ->|         |
        nginx:443
```

also proxying HTTPS to Varnish you better add these headers:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
```

then on nginx:8000 receiving part you have to add real ip:

```
set_real_ip_from   127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
```

otherwise it will be a mess.
this way Varnish:80 will always catch direct user request, and nginx:443 will decrypt ssl to Varnish and then Varnish will send non-cached request to nginx:8000

this configuration a bit cleaner, but really hard to say why you have 30+sec.

Comment: well, all traffic goes through ssl, so no need to have port 80 open to public. i'll try adding headers tomorrow

Comment: obviously in your config you dont have any redirect to 443 server, and nginx just listening on port 80...

Comment: The first `server` block is just there for testing purpose. The second `server` block is on listening 443. And putting in the headers did not help with the 30+sec issue...